# Way of checking if a bookmark exists from SAS using DDE connection to Word

Tags: ms-word, sas, dde

I am using SAS v9.4, running a DDE connection to Word 2010.

Once I have connected to a word document, I would like to be able to check from withing SAS whether a specific bookmark exists or not. Is this possible withing the DDE framework?

I have tried adding the if statement, but it looks like the command `Bookmarks.Exist` isn't recognised.

```
filename sas2word dde 'winword|system';
data _null_;
    file sas2word;
    if put '[Bookmarks.Exists("Bkm1")]' then do;
       put '[EditGoTo.Destination = "Bkm1"]';
       put '[Insert "Test"]';
       end;
run;
```

But it just crashes and comes up with.

> "The Bookmark does not exist"

Is there a way to query the Word document so we can avoid the pop-up/crash? Or, if not, is there a way to run a try-catch loop within the code so it keeps running?

Also sorry if the tags are not accurate, wasn't sure exactly what this question fell under so I tagged all three options - feel free to edit if inappropriate.

Comment: Your logic is very mixed up.  You have a PUT statement in the place where IF is expecting the condition to be tested.  PUT is for writing text.  If you wanted to read something from DDE then you would need an INPUT statement instead.  Not sure what you could read though unless you some how wrote word commands that would generate some other document that SAS could then read back later.

Comment: DOCX files are zipped XML files. IMO it's significantly easier to pull this information from the XML files than it is from the DOCX files. Or VB will do this and you can call the VB script from SAS.